# Error de Memória em Python

Tags: c, python-3.x

Estou tentado a dias resolver este problema e não consigo, meu scripts funciona
em varias maquinas com python, mas no servidor que preciso rodar a aplicação não
e apresenta o erro, já deixei um teste de memoria rodando por três dias e as memorias estão perfeitas.

```
str_grande = ''.join((str(y) for y in list(sys.stdin.readline())))
x = [int(e) for e in str_grande.split()]

------------------------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "welton.py", line 12, in 
str_grande = ''.join((str(y) for y in list(sys.stdin.readline())))
MemoryError
Command exited with non-zero status (1)
```

Se executo o programa em C, ele funciona perfeitamente! Mas como preciso do integração com Python para subfunções não posso usar o C. Nesta linguagem eu uso
o "long long int" existe alguma estrutura em Python similar? OBS: lista e dicionários tem limite de tamanho! Em lista não aceita +12.000 elementos

Equipamento é:!
1.4GHz Quad-Core ARM Cortex-A5
Rede sem fio 2.4GHz e 5GHz IEEE 802.11.b / g / n / ac, Bluetooth 4.2, BLE
Gigabit Ethernet via USB 2.0 (throughput máximo de 300Mbps)
1 GB de RAM
CPU de 64 bits
4 portas USB
Saída estéreo de 4 pólos e porta de vídeo composto
Tamanho completo HDMI
Soquete Ethernet 10/100 BaseT
Porta Micro SD para carregar seu sistema operacional Ubuntu e armazenar dados

Comment: não seria melhor processar os dados linhas por linha para não estourar a memória?
Tipo: `for line in sys.stdin: print(int(line))`

Comment: E o que seu código deveria fazer?

Comment: Ele deve pegar um volume de Números de 1 ate 99999, processar algumas regras, e depois dar o resultado. Os numeros são aleatórias e podem ser sequências de 3 ou ate sequências de 99999!

Comment: Ele deve pegar uma quantidade absurda de dados processar até chegar num determinado ponto, e recomeçar a captura de dados agora só totalizando!